# Complex Searching with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, search

I am curious about what methods do you use for complex searching with NHibernate ?

I am using [Ayende's](http://ayende.com/Blog/2006/12/07/ComplexSearchingQueryingWithNHibernate.aspx)

What is yours ?
Thanks for your advices and answers.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a complex dynamic search, we will usually construct a SearchParameter object and then pass that into a method that will build our criteria for us.

For example, if we were searching for a person we might have a search object that looks like this:

```
public class PersonSearchParameters
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public ICriteria GetSearchCriteria()
    {
        DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof (Person));
        //Add query parameters
        Return query;
    }
}
```

Then for each type of search, we'll be able to create the single criteria from the class, or we could have multple search parameter classes and chain them together

Comment: That's the same i use
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We use HQL, but  we're still trying to wrap our heads around the Criteria API for complex queries. We have to manage a lot of duplication when using HQL.

Comment: I am not a master at HQL at all but it seems that building complex queries with DetachedCriteria looks easier.

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I use pretty much Ayende's too jsut a bit more complex, what do you want to do that you cant do with that?

Basically what we added is that we have an interface where we define all the fields where we want to search and we call this when we are about to make the search which means that we can easily change what we are searching for.

Also we are using Active Record in the project ( on top of Hibernate) and tis pretty cool, loads of tasks gets simplified , thou the lack of docs does hurt sometimes
Cheer

Comment: the interface thing sounds great, could you please post some code here or somewhere might be my mail address